# Current date brings back time as well

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get the date only, I wrote this:

```
func getCurrentDate() -> Date {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    let result = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(result)

    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: result)
    return date!
}
```

printing 'result' I get:

```
12.07.2019
```

which is what I need, but converting it to Date type and printing it results in:

```
2019-07-11 21:00:00 +0000
```

Why does that happen and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Don't worry about the debugging output of a `Date` object. Whenever you wish to display a `Date` to user, use `DateFormatter` with the proper styles.

Comment: You live with 3 hours difference from UTC, no? So it's really 12/07/19 at midhnight in UTC, but in your current area, it's not midnight.

Comment: it's 00:00:00 your zone is 3 also what operation you need a `Date` for ? can't you use `result` directly ?

Comment: I need to return a Date type so I can't use 'result'. I don't talk about the day difference, I understood it is because of the UTC, what I do care for is the format, why do I get the 21:00:00 +0000 while I'm creating a date from 12.07.2019 only.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` was very unfortunately named. It has nothing to do with dates. It represents an instant in time. An instant that all observers (ignoring details like Relativity) would agree on. It isn't "a day on the calendar." It's a point in time, independent of any calendar.

The fact that it prints out in a "calendar-like" way is just a convenience for debugging.

If you want "a specific day on a calendar" then the tools you want is `DateComponents` and `Calendar`, not `Date`:

```
func currentDay() -> DateComponents {
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
}
```

Keep in mind that the user's current calendar may not be Gregorian. If you require the Gregorian calendar, you need to say so:

```
func currentDay() -> DateComponents {
    return Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], 
                                                           from: Date())
}
```

The Gregorian calendar is the one where the current year is 2019. In the Hebrew calendar, it's 5779. In the Buddhist calendar, it's 2562. In the Islamic calendar, it's 1440. There is no one "correct" calendar, which is why you need to provide one.

Reading your comments, it's possible you mean "the start of 'today' using the current calendar." If that's what you want, then you would use this:

```
func currentDay() -> Date {
    return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
}
```

(Or use the Gregorian calendar if needed, though I don't believe any supported calendar disagrees about what the start of the day is.)